# Is there a way for my web page to tell the browser to clear the cache of a file?

Tags: caching, azure-blob-storage, browser-cache

My web app will put the user's avatar in Azure BLOB storage. That has a cache expiration of 1 week. Works great, the user logs in, their avatar is in the cache, it displays with no https I/O needed.

But when they update their avatar, if the filename is the same (I use their filename), then I need it to be removed from the cache so it is downloaded again. Is there a way I can tell the browser to clear the cache of a specific file? Or of all files from a specific domain?

And yes I can add `?foo=guid_value` to force a download every time. But I want caching as 99.9% of the time, across all the different avatars & thumbnails, it saves time.

Answer (score 0):

Each blob in Azure Storage has some system properties (like etag and last-modified) that gets changed only when the blob is modified. These properties can be used for caching purposes.

What you can do is append one of these properties in your blob URL (so your URL would be something like `https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/avatar.png?last-modified=2023-09-27T00:00:00Z`).

Considering the browser will cache the content based on the entire URL, the content will be cached until the user updates the blob.

This would obviously require you to store one of these system properties in your application database so that you can construct the URL properly (or store the entire URL in the database). Also, you would need to update these properties (or update the URL) in your database after the user has modified the blob.